# Move a bootstrap column's content that is a button to very bottom

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

**My HTML**

```
<div class="col-sm-5">some content</div>
<div class="col-sm-1">
    <button class="fa fa-plus-circle" type="button"></button>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">some other content</div>
```

**My css**

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 10px;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
color: #fff;
margin: 0px auto;
text-align: center;
font-size: 40px;
```

I want to make the plus button to come down. By the above codes it will come to the exact correct position however col-sm-6 sticks itself to the left because the button is absolute.

**I'm using bootstrap 3**

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Please tag your question with the version of Bootstrap you're using. If 4, you have flex available, which makes this easier.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-5">some content</div>
//put all other content you want in a grid-1 here
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
<button class="fa fa-plus-circle" type="button"></button>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6">some other content</div>
//content for the remaining grid-2
```

This should probably make your design as 
 
-- Grid 1 
-- Plus Circle  
-- Grid 2

The mistake you are doing is that you aren't following bootstrap grid convention here.

Also, For some reason, you haven't described class, ID, Tag on which you have added CSS.

Lastly, Make sure your CSS is below bootstrap CSS.